# Am I eligible for a Dutch passport when only my grandparents had citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, dutch-citizens

Hoping someone can help me here, I am wanting to apply for a Dutch passport.

My grandparents were born in Holland as was my father, but they moved to South Africa when he was 3 or so. from what I understand they applied for citizenship in South Africa so he doesn't have for Holland. My dad passed away when I was 13 and he never applied for Dutch citizenship. I read about the rule that over 28 I might have missed my chance, is there a way I can still apply?

Comment: If your father somehow retained his Dutch citizenship (for example, if he did not receive South African nationality together with his parents), and did not lose it before you were born, then you might have been Dutch when you were born.  This is unlikely.  Even in that case, however, you probably would have lost your Dutch nationality on your 28th birthday.  If you are over 28, I'm afraid there is little hope.  Still, it can't hurt to ask at the Dutch consulate.  They might be able to pinpoint exactly when your father or you lost Dutch nationality.

Comment: @phoog 1.  Why isn't that comment an answer?  2.  According to wikipedia (I know, I know) you only lose Dutch citizenship on naturalization if you are an adult at the time - is that wrong?

Comment: @MartinBonner a minor loses Dutch citizenship on naturalization if the Dutch parent naturalizes and the minor is included in the naturalization.  There are various exceptions, but that is the general principle.  I probably posted that as a comment because the presented facts are insufficient for a comprehensive answer.  Also, because we get a lot of Dutch nationality questions from people who never log in after asking the question, I'm not inclined to post a detailed answer unless I have some indication that the asker is actually going to see it, so I tend to post a comment to test that.